# When I try to save an entity I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I try to save an entity I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I am able to create a new entity, the code is almost the same.

When I try to save the entity I am able to trace a bit of the code
My Controller code looks like this:

```
  _entities.Kandidaats.Attach(kandidaatBewerken,true);
  _entities.SubmitChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

When I trace the code, I see that my kandidaatBewerken holds the right data, on the first line, after that the trace goes back to my view code and gives the error on the second line:

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
<%= Html.TextBox("KandidaatId", Model.KandidaatId)%>
```

When I trace it, it says that my Model is empty, while just a handling before this one, it is filled.

Why do I get this error and how can I move forward?

Comment: Please permit me an offtopic comment that using non-english words in code is a very bad practice unless it's your own little project and you never expect to share it with anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess here.. because there's not a whole lot of code to go on..

But the "Index" view is creating a form to edit your Kandidaat object...

However, you're redirecting your user to the form without a populated model (which is why the second line throws an error.. model is null and you're calling a property on a null object).

try:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", kandidaatBewerken);
```

But that will take you back to the form (which may be your desired result).. I would take the user back to whatever action generated the list, or the another route...

```
return RedirectToAction("List");
```

or

```
return RedirectToRoute("Home");
```

Comment: I've found a part of the problem now, the Kandidaat Model isn't in the right format, that's why it goes back to my view, but without the right viewdata